# Como pegar valor de um Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Eu tenho o seguinte comando

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataDoDesligamento)
```

Nele é colocado uma data, e ao clicar em um botão deveria redirecionar para um relatório, só que eu preciso passar pra URL o parâmetro dataDesligamento para mandar pro relatório especifico, da seguinte forma.

```
<a target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-red" href="~/Relatorio/Relatorio.aspx?dataReferencia=@dataDesligamento">Simular desligamento</a>
```

E não faço a mínima idéia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Use pode ser facilmente resolvido no JavaScript, você está utilizando [tag:Jquery]?

Comment: Como eu consigo resolver através disso?

Comment: No front-end da página, você irá pegar o valor do campo quando o usuário clicar no botão de ir para o relatório (irei criar minha reposta com mais informações), você não respondeu minha dúvida, você está usando Jquery no seu projeto?

Comment: @ThaynaValadares Seja mais específica. Qual é o código que gera aquele href?

Comment: Não está sendo utilizado jquery

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com `javascript` uma função para pegar o valor do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataDoDesligamento)`, criar uma `URL` e abrir em uma página com essa URL.

O `helper` `EditorFor` irá gerar um elemento que tem como `id` o mesmo nome da propriedade.

Sendo assim, dentro da sua página, adicione 1 botão e no evento `onclick` chame a `function` `redirecionar()` que iremos criar.

```
<button onclick="redirecionar()" >Simular desligamento</button>
```

Abaixo, abra uma tag para escrever código `javascript` e crie a function

```
<script>
    function redirecionar(){
      var dataDoDesligamento = document.getElementById("DataDoDesligamento").value;
      window.open("~/Relatorio/Relatorio.aspx?dataReferencia="+dataDoDesligamento,'_blank');
    }    
</script>
```